That grid of hidden pins on a micro sdcard, how do I use them?
About 15 years ago Sandisk released their "Sansa SlotRadio" thing. Basically, it's a regular mp3 player with an sdcard preloaded with music.
Well, the music mafia being the music mafia, there's DRM involved, which would make an interesting project to try and defeat.
On the sdcard is a sticker. And behind the sticker is... A grid of pins!
Infact, it looks SUSPICIOUSLY similar to the ones data recovery centers use when doing low level stuff on physically broken cards.
Anyone have any info on this? It's three rows and seven columns, with (2,2) missing and (2,5) much smaller.


Including a photo in your question of the micro sdcard and the grid of pins would make it easier to identify what it is.

Let me do that.
